# How to Add spinner to SLDS VF page when button is clicked

Tags: visualforce, controller, slds, actionfunction

I must be missing something here because the spinner does not show up, but not sure where the problem is. What am I missing?

```
<li class="slds-button-group-item">
   <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" value="Search" action="{!doAdvSearch}" status = "recordSearchid" />
      <apex:actionStatus id="recordSearchid">
        <apex:facet name="start">
          <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:4rem">
           <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_inline">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
               <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
               <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </apex:facet>
      </apex:actionStatus>
</li>
```

Comment: Answered here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191203/visualforce-with-slds-spinner-embedded-in-a-page-layout

Comment: I have been looking at that post, but still not working for me.

Comment: Is it necessary to have a rerender in my command button?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code & pass action status id into your commanLink status :

```
<apex:actionStatus id="myAjaxStatus" >
        <apex:facet name="start" >
            <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.25; z-index: 1000; background-color: black;">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 15% 50%">
                <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px; background-color: #fff; width: 125px;">
                    <img src="/img/loading.gif" style="float: left; margin: 8px;" />
                    <span style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px 0px;">Please Wait...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
```

Comment: Your code will replace the lightning spinner with the loading gif from classic. I would say that he should stick with his original code, but add the apex:facet name="start" piece as that is why his actionStatus is currently not working. @Ivo Dimov - take a look at adding the facet to your actionStatus.

Comment: I did add the apex:facet, but still the spinner is not loading. I moved the spinner outside my button on top of my page, and I could see it working. Wonder if there is anything that needs to be set up on the button itself.